# remove duplicate values from multidimensional array by single value

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Ok the thing is, Ive read and tried a lot of solutions found here based on complete duplicateness, BUT I need something a little bit different and cant figure it out...

Because I only want to get and remove the duplicate value if only 1 of the array values is duplicate.
And also later combine the two but that's not that difficult.

```
$a = array(
    array(
        'id' => 1,
        'qty' => 1
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 0,
        'qty' => 1
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 1,
        'qty' => 2
    )
);
```

What I want the outcome to be:

```
$b = array(
    array(
        'id' => 1,
        'qty' => 3
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 0,
        'qty' => 1
    )
);
```

Comment: Please, ask specific questions instead of asking for someone to do the work for you. What have you tried? http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/

Comment: why not merge the arrays with key values and make a new array with it? That way you wont have duplicates.. is there a reason you want to remove the duplicates? Only the quantity changes from what I'm understanding.

Comment: @PedroMoreira - Im sorry Im not showing what I've tried. Like I said I tried a lot of multidimensional array sorting answers here but they all focused on being a full duplicate, so id ánd qty being equal. Since im not that familiar with Multidimensional arrays I thought I could ask for help..
alda1234 - A lot changes but this is just a small example of how the situation could be. I thought about merging but again couldn't solve it myself

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do something like the following:

```
<?php
$a = array(
    array(
        'id' => 1,
        'qty' => 1
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 0,
        'qty' => 1
    ),
    array(
        'id' => 1,
        'qty' => 2
    )
);

$idsList = array();
$res = array();
foreach ($a as $arr){
  if (!in_array($arr['id'], $idsList)){
    $res[$arr['id']] = $arr;
    $idsList[] = $arr['id'];
  }
  else{
      $res[$arr['id']]['qty'] += $arr['qty'];

  }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($res);
```

To get array like that:

```
Array
(
    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [qty] => 3
        )

    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 0
            [qty] => 1
        )

)
```

Checkout This DEMO: http://codepad.org/UP0G7WnE

Comment: choose yours because it wasn't dependent on the other values in the array, thanks for your quick/great answer!

Answer (score 3):

```
$a = array(
array(
    'id' => 1,
    'qty' => 1
),
array(
    'id' => 0,
    'qty' => 1
),
array(
    'id' => 1,
    'qty' => 2
)
);

$b = array();
$ids = array();
for($i = 0; $i < count($a); $i++)
{ 
  if(in_array($a[$i]['id'], $ids))
  {    
    $j = array_search($a[$i]['id'], array_values($ids));    
    $b[$j]['qty'] += $a[$i]['qty'];
  }
 else
 {
   $b[$i]['id'] = $a[$i]['id'];
   $b[$i]['qty'] = $a[$i]['qty'];
   $ids[] = $a[$i]['id'];
 }
}

echo "<pre>";
print_r($b);
```

Answer (score 2):

This could be a solution:

```
$temp = array();

foreach ($a as $data){

    if (isset($temp[$data['id']])){
        $temp[$data['id']] += $data['qty'];             
    } else {
        $temp[$data['id']] = $data['qty'];
    }

}

// Format array

$b = array();

foreach ($temp as $id => $qty){

    $b[] = array(
        'id' => $id,
        'qty' => $qty
    );  

}
```

Output will be:

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [id] => 1
            [qty] => 3
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [id] => 0
            [qty] => 1
        )

)
```